# Use BibTeX By Unique LaTeX File

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm using Inlage to write my thesis. I made a `.bib` file and I want to use it to obtain my bibliography. I have one `.tex` file where I include all the others.

```
\documentclass[dvips,letterpaper,12pt, openright]{report}
\usepackage{thesis}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\include{Chap1}
\include{Chap2}

\end{document}
```

What do I have to do in order to use the same bib file for all chapters? And which command do I need to use?

Comment: Do you want a bibliography to appear at the end of each chapter, or just one bibliography to appear at the end of the thesis?

Comment: I want the bibliography at the end of the thesis, and  how can i use the cite in the other chapters.

Answer (score 2):

You should just put

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} %whatever style you prefer
\bibliography{./bibliography_file}% Produces the bibliography via BibTeX.
```

before

```
\end{document}
```

in the main file. The bibliography filename goes without the .bib extension.
You refer to an entry with the \cite command:

```
\cite{myentry}.
```

The Include statements in latex just load the source in your main document during processing. Run bibtex after latex and then latex again, twice.

Answer (score 1):

Because the *contents* of your chapters will be included in the one LaTeX file you're typesetting, those chapters can reference entries in your BibTeX file the usual way:

```
some amazing discovery~\cite{myentry}.
```

And at the end of your thesis file, just include these lines above your `\end{document}`:

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{mybibfile}
```

Comment: The label name is correct and also the file bib name but i have this: Package natbib Warning: Citation `Coh' on page 1 undefined

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex`, `bibtex`, `pdflatex` and `pdflatex` on `yourfile.tex` in this order.